# Facebook-C#-sdk: v5 Security exception

Tags: security, exception, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm still new with facebook C# sdk (ASP.net) I'm using Facebook C# SDK v5 sample "CSASPNETFacebookApp" everything well when in the development machine, but when I upload it on my Godaddy Shared Hosting I got a secuirity exception:

> Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy. To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.
>
> Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationPermission, System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' failed.

Please advise me on how I can fix this? Or its better to change a hosting server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had this issue and fixed it by adding a "trust level" setting of Full to the system.web section of the web.config file:

```
<system.web>
    <trust level="Full" />
```

Check out this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tkscy493.aspx) for details and implications of setting this.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Andy, but are you also using Godaddy as your host? Please advise me. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Jeff, I am using WinHost, no reason why this won't work with other providers though.

Comment: +1 Worked for me too. Got this error out of the blue at Godaddy.

Answer (score 0):

```
<section name="facebookSettings" type="Facebook.FacebookConfigurationSection" requirePermission="false" />
```